# How to get the latest event‘s element(should filter null value) that group by some keys

Tags: filter, esper, maxby

I am a new using `esper`, I got a problem that did not know how to construct the EPL.

my event has these elements(key,index,e0,e1,e2....) ,and in every event e1 may exist or not, I want get latest `"index"'s element:“e1”`(exluding null value) and sum(e2) group by “key”.

I wrote a EPL like this:

```
 select key, sum(e2), maxby(index).e1 as e1 from Event.win:time_batch(3 sec) group by key
```

example output like below:

```
send event :{key=0, index=0, e0=5, e1=1}

send event :{**key=3**, index=1, **e1=2**, e2=6}

send event :{**key=3**, index=2, e0=0, e3=2}   **//the event e1 is not exist**

send event :{key=1, index=3, e2=8, e3=4}

sliding win output： {key=0, sum(e2)=null, e1=1}

sliding win output： {key=1, sum(e2)=8, e1=null}

sliding win output： {**key=3**, sum(e2)=6, **e1=null**}
```

you see ,the result of [key=3]'s e1=null, but i expect to filter the e1=null event and should output e1=2

`"maxby"` can not add a condition like `"fmax"` function.

so how can I filter it in EPL?

Answer (score 0):

just add "...from Event(e1 is not null)..."

Comment: but your EPL filter the event that e1 is null:“{**key=3**, index=2, e0=0, e3=2}”, e3=2 will remove too, I can not remove this evnet if i need aggregate e3. @user650839

Comment: I think doing something like "maxby(case when e1 is null then null else index end)" since "maxby" can take any expression including a call to a UDF.

Comment: "maxby(case when e1 is null then null else index end)"----It works， thank you~~~~~@user650839. you really helped me.   ..  buut, when I try to get the e1 `minby` index group key as similar above, it didn't work， i write like this:`minby(case when e1 is null then null else index end)` 

send event :{key=0, index=12, e2=6, e3=3}

send event :{key=0, index=13, **e1=4**} 

sliding win output： {key=0, sum(e2)=6, **e1=null**}

   why it can't work? how to write it?